# No button links

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Trying to deal with buttons with C# Core MVC

But I still don't understand the logic.
Help me please.

Here I have a controller method (GroupsController)

```
  public ActionResult AgentParams(int? groupID, int? packageID)
    {
        return ApiResult(new GroupAgentParamsModel(groupID, packageID).LoadData(Dao));
    }
```

I can use it via button.

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.RouteUrl("GroupAgentParams", new { groupID = Model.Group.DataId })">Agent Params</a>
```

this button has a link:

```
https://localhost:5001/Group/2/AgentParams
```

But there are other controller methods
But I can call like above method I can't.
Here is an example (GroupsController):

```
  public ActionResult WorkModes(int? id)
    {
        return ApiResult(LoadData(id.Value));
    }
```

button:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.RouteUrl("GroupWorkModes", new { id = Model.Group.DataId })"></a>
```

this button has no link and doesn't work at all.

why?

Comment: you have not provide text like `Agent Params` you have done for the first link

Comment: @viveknuna If you place text inside the tag, the links do not appear. These are just labels on the buttons and shouldn't affect the link.

Comment: try @Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "User" }) like format

Comment: @Url.RouteUrl("WorkModes", new { controller = "Groups", action = "WorkModes", id = Model.Group.DataId })

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to deal with buttons with C# Core MVC

Could you try  [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ? The attribute names are prefixed with `asp-` .

```
<a class="btn btn-default" asp-controller="Groups"
   asp-action="AgentParams"
   asp-route-groupID=1> Agent Params</a>

<a class="btn btn-default" asp-controller="Groups"
   asp-action="WorkModes"
   asp-route-id=1> Work Modes</a>
```

result:
[image]

Read [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#anchor-tag-helper-attributes) to know more.